# Inserting a $ in the replace string in a regular espression

Tags: javascript, regex

Does anyone know why

```
"why?? <abc> and <a b c> and <a b>".replace( /<([^>]+)>/g, "\$$1" );
```

Returns

```
"why?? $1 and $1 and $1"
```

insted of

```
"why?? $abc and $a b c and $a b"
```

without the escaped $, the result is as expected

```
"why?? <abc> and <a b c> and <a b>".replace( /<([^>]+)>/g, "$1" )
//"why?? abc and a b c and a b"
```

I tried all sort of hacks, including for example

```
"why?? <abc> and <a b c> and <a b>".replace( /<([^>]+)>/g, String.fromCharCode( 36 ) + "$1" );
```

In the end I managed to get the output I wanted using a function as a replace string (see below) but I would like to know what I was doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
"why?? <abc> and <a b c> and <a b>".replace( /<([^>]+)>/g, function(m,m1,m2,p){return '$' + m1; } )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JavaScript, backslashes are simply dropped from unrecognized escapes sequences. `\$` is not a recognized escape sequence in a string literal, so this:

```
"\$$1"
```

means the same as this:

```
"$$1"
```

and in a `replace` replacement-string, `$$` means "a literal dollar sign".

What you want is this:

```
"$$$1"
```

where the `$$` becomes `$` and the `$1` becomes e.g. `abc`.

(In other words: the way that you "escape" a dollar sign in a `replace` replacement string is by doubling it, *not* by prefixing it with a backslash.)

Comment: That's grat, thanks. It still doesn't explain why "why?? <abc> and <a b c> and <a b>".replace( /<([^>]+)>/g, String.fromCharCode( 36 ) + "$1" ) wouldn't work, but it's enough for me, thanks! :-)

Comment: @fritzfromlondon: `String.fromCharCode( 36 )` is `"$"`, so `String.fromCharCode( 36 ) + "$1"` is `"$$1"`, which in a `replace` replacement-string means "a literal dollar sign followed by the digit one".